# how to create a prgram that can detect and display leap year calendar in c language

Tags: c, calendar

what is the command to write to display a month in leap year? I tried to use this command but output I got is wrong.

```
    if ((year % 4 == 0)
        return 29;
    else
        return 28;
}
else
{
    int daysInMonth[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    return daysInMonth[monthNumber];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: As an aside... Ignoring the syntax errors and incomplete code, `year % 4 == 0` by itself does not accurately determine if a year is a leap year.

Answer (score 2):

LEAP YEAR:  Basically, as most of us already know, a year is not a perfect 365 days in length, it's closer to 365.25.

Therefore, every four years, we add a day to February making it 29 days.  But that is not perfect.  So every 100 years (centennial, like 1800, 1900, etc) we do NOT add a day to February.  But that is not quite perfect still -- so every 4th centennial (2000, 2400, 2800...) we DO add a day to February.

And that's worked out pretty well so far...

The `IS_LEAP_YEAR()` macro considers each factor just discussed: you can see
it cares for the modulus of 4, and of 100, and 400 too.

Here then, is the code that will get you past your current sticking point.  The tested, runnable version is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/evvEY96c9):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_LEAP_YEAR(yr) (!((yr)%400) || (!((yr)%4) && (((yr)%100)))  )

int days_in_month(int year, int month)
{
    int daysInMonth[] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if(IS_LEAP_YEAR(year))
        daysInMonth[2]= 29;

    return daysInMonth[month];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int year = 2000, mon = 2;

    
    printf("year: %d  month: %d  has %d days.\n", 
        year, mon, days_in_month(year, mon));
    
    return 0;
}
```